# Buenas practicas de uso de Base de datos y String.xml

Tags: android, base-de-datos

Una base de datos con **varias tablas**. Una de ellas por ejemplo `transporte` con los siguientes atributos:

- `Nombre`
- `Descripción`
- `Precio`

En un principio la aplicación estará disponible en dos idiomas.

¿Que guardar en la Base de datos? Es decir, la descripción deberá de estar en Español e Ingles. Entonces en la BD, en el campo descripción ¿guardo el nombre de la variable que estará alojada en el fichero `string.xml` de cada idioma? y en `string.xml` de cada idioma estará escrito el contenido.

De lo contrario la base de datos deberá de tener un campo por cada atributo multilingüe. Por ejemplo:

- `Nombre_es`
- `Nombre_en`
- `Descripcion_es`
- `Descripcion_en`
- `Precio`

Pero este segundo caso creo que complica mas la app porque dependiendo de el idioma actual del usuario se realizarán distintas consultas SQL.

Cual es la mejor practica para desarrollar en este tipo de casos?

**Edito**

Como ejemplo he puesto el contenido de `1 tabla` de la BD pero contendrá varias tablas relacionales. De ahí viene la duda. Para llevar a cavo algunas tareas, serán necesarias las consultas a la BD con sus `inner join` y demás comandos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se tratara únicamente de localizar la interfaz de usuario, Android ya dispone de soporte para la localización utilizando recursos como `strings.xml`

Más información sobre localización en Android: [Localizing with Resources](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Pero sin embargo por lo que entiendo necesitas que los datos que almacenas en tu base de datos sean localizables. En este caso lo mejor es tener un esquema multidioma en tu BD.

Ejemplo: (Ignora los tipos de datos)

[image: Esquema multi-idioma]

De esta manera en la tabla principal tendrías la llave primaria y todos aquellos atributos que no varían según el idioma, como por ejemplo precios, cantidades fechas etc.

En una tabla intermedia entre la tabla principal y la tabla idioma tendrás una fila por cada combinación transporte-idioma que contiene los datos que si varían por idioma, en tu caso `Nombre` y `Descripcion`

Comment: Este sistema es interesante, pero en caso de que la BD fuese de mas tablas se complica bastante ¿no? Incluso siendo así de simple, las consultas SQL serían distintas por cada idioma ¿no? Por ejemplo para realizar un `select` se tendría que ir modificando el campo where indicado el ìdIdioma`¿Correcto?

Comment: Cada tabla que requiera almacenar texto de manera localizable debería seguir el mismo esquema.  De la misma manera todas las consultas que requieran localización deberán recibir como parámetro el IdIdioma,  esto no debe ser problema si todas las páginas incluyen este id en URL (O código estilo 'es' ,  'en' )

Answer (score 0):

Para entrar en contexto, si usas archivos `strings.xml` definidos para un idioma, no necesitas una base de datos para guardar alguna información, a menos que desees un esquema diferente al de localización.

Creo que en este caso deberías aprovechar el soporte con el que cuenta Android para cambiar la información de tu UI en base a la configuración de idioma.  El esquema de localización requiere que crees folders y archivos conteniendo el texto y su identificador en diferentes lenguajes según lo requieras, que serán soportados por tu aplicación.

Por ejemplo, si suponemos que nuestra aplicación soporta idiomas inglés, español y rumano, debemos tener los siguientes folders....

El folder de textos default sería:

```
res/values/strings.xml
```

El folder para agregar los textos en ingles:

```
res/values-en/strings.xml
```

contendría:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nom">Crazy Dog</string>
    <string name="desc">Crazy dog Transportation, the best company</string>
</resources>
```

El folder para agregar los textos en español es:

```
res/values-es/strings.xml
```

contendría:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nom">Perro Loco</string>
    <string name="desc">Transportes Perro Loco, la mejor empresa</string>
</resources>
```

El folder para agregar los textos en rumano :

```
res/values-ro/strings.xml
```

contendría:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nom">Câine nebun</string>
    <string name="desc">companie de transport Câine nebun, cea mai buna companie.</string>
</resources>
```

Tendrías algo similar a esto en tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simplemente esas descripciones definidas en tus `strings.xml` las usas en donde sea requerido en tu aplicación:

```
String strNombre = context.getResources().getString(R.string.nom);
textViewName.setText(strNombre);
String strDescripcion = context.getResources().getString(R.string.desc)  
textViewDesc.setText(strDescripcion);
```

**La gran ventaja es que automáticamente, dependiendo del lenguaje definido en tu sistema operativo carga los textos definidos en el archivo `strings.xml` del lenguaje correspondiente.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Mi punto de vista con respecto a tus preguntas:

> ¿Que guardar en la Base de datos? Es decir, la descripción deberá de
>   estar en Español e Ingles. Entonces en la BD, en el campo descripción

No creo conveniente ni necesario combinar para este caso combinar el uso de una base de datos con strings.xml. Si se opta por usar una base de datos, usaría el mismo esquema usado por "Android Localization". La base de datos contendría tablas textos_es y textos_en, que contendría los mismos nombres de campos

```
Nombre
Descripcion
Precio
```

Simplemente decides de que tabla tomar los textos y el código necesario para mostrarlos no tendría que cambiar.

Considero es una ventaja mayor en lugar de una única tabla con diferentes nombres de campo:

```
Nombre_es
Nombre_en
Descripcion_es
Descripcion_en
Precio
```

Que en código tendrías que validar en que campo usar, se volvería innecesariamente más complejo si en un futuro tuvieras soporte para otros idiomas...

> ¿guardo el nombre de la variable que estará alojada en el fichero
>   string.xml de cada idioma?

No es necesario guardar en una base de datos el nombre de la variable, la variable es la misma dentro de los strings.xml, pero el contenido en cada archivo estaría en diferentes idiomas.

**En este caso, la ventaja de usar Strings.xml sobre una base de datos, es primeramente el rápido acceso a los mismos por medio de la clase R y el código necesario para la implementación es minimo.**

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @Elenasys pero creo que no entendiste bien mi pregunta. Desde el principio tengo claro el funcionamiento del fichero string.xml, por ello la duda es si usar una base de datos genérica y en los campos multilingües insertar el nombre de la variable escrita en los ficheros string.xml o adaptar la base de datos para que tengas campos específicos para cada idioma.

Comment: Simplemente no veo necesario combinar entre el uso de los strings.xml y la base de datos o viceversa. He editado mi respuesta para más información. Veo que me dieron -1 porque seguramente no entienden el uso de los strings.xml. Tengo un par de aplicaciones con soporte para Alemán, Rumano, Español, Inglés y Griego las cuales usan en un promedio 25 textos y no he tenido la necesidad de implementar una base de datos para administrar los textos... :)

Comment: La ventaja de usar Strings.xml sobre una base de datos, es primeramente el rápido acceso a los mismos por medio de la clase R y el código necesario es minimo.

Comment: @aldakur pienso que si tu pregunta tiene de trasfondo, cual es la mejor manera de manejar multiples idiomas en Android. Creo que esta respuesta es la que buscas. No se si me estoy perdiendo algo pero parece que quieres hacer una rueda nueva, la pregunta entonces seria necesito una rueda nueva para este fin o quiero aprender a fabricar ruedas, si ambas son, no, pienso que el enfoque de esta respuesta es el adecuado. Saludos

Comment: He editado la pregunta para aclarar la confusión que creo que esta causando en algunos usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

También hay la opción de integrar multi-idioma en una base de datos, implementando la técnica que usa el plugin `QTranslate` de Wordpress

En los campos, donde requieres tenerlos en más de un idioma:

- Nombre
- Descripción

Por cada idioma a incluir lo puedes englobar y identificarlo:

```
<!--:es-->Nombre producto<!--:--><!--:en-->Name of product<!--:-->
<!--:es-->Descipción del producto<!--:--><!--:en-->Description of product<!--:-->
```

La siguiente función sirve para extraer una cadena con un idioma en concreto.

```
public static String getText(String text, String lang) {
    String r = "<!--:" + lang + "-->(.*?)<!--:-->";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(r);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    if (m.find( )) {
        return m.group(1);
    } else return "";
}
```

Su uso en PseudoCode

```
String Name = getDataOfTable("productos","nombre") //cargar los datos desde la BD
Name = getText(Name,"es"); //para obtener la cadena en español
```